# iOS CATextLayer wrapped doesn't work as expected

Tags: xcode, word-wrap, catextlayer

I have a CATextLayer with multiline Text.
The wrapped option is set to YES. But it doesn't wrap the text on the last line. 
If I add another line with \n and a space, the wrapping occurs (but this destroys the layout).

This only happens in iOS >= 8.3

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 4):

Something in `CATextLayer` has changed in iOS 8.3 which means that you now need to add 1px more to the height than you did before. If you were using `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` then this now totals to 2px additional height.

It's an odd breakage but there's not much that can be done about that.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made [LabelKit](https://github.com/edudnyk/LabelKit) project that does a CoreText drawn animation of the text. It supports animation of multiline text too, and keeps the benefits of layout constraints content sizing while animating.

`CATextLayer` makes CoreGraphics text drawing, and letters there a wider and are not being layout in multiline layer properly.